# Getting a "Unexpected field at makeError" when uploading a form

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, multer

My form has an input for a file (in my case an image) and for some text. When I hit the submit button, the stated error occurs. I have had the issue for two days now and I tried to understand where the problem was, but my efforts were in vain and I have decided to yield and seek assistance.

Here is my controller for the image:

```
// using this to generate a random name for an image
var possible = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789',
    imgUrl = '';

// this is just a loop to create a 10 character random name
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    imgUrl += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() *
              possible.length));
}

/* I saw an answer to a similar question where the correct answer author 
said path will always refer to folder where the input folder resides */

var tempPath = req.file.path,
    ext = path.extname(req.file.path).toLower(),
    targetPath = './app/controller/store/' + imgUrl + ext;

// Check if image is of the correct format
if (ext === '.png' || ext === '.jpg' || ext === '.jpeg' || ext === '.gif')
{
    fs.rename(tempPath, targetPath, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.redirect('/posts/'+ imgUrl);
    });
} else {
    fs.unlink(tempPath, function () {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(500, {error: 'Only image files are allowed.'});
    });

var post = new Post({
    content: req.body.content,
    author: req.user,
    filename: imgUrl + ext
});

post.save(function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: getErrorMessage(err)
        });
    } else res.json(post);
});
}
```

And here is the form:

```
<form method="post" action="/posts" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <textarea name="content"></textarea>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Post">
</form>
```

I did the usual stuff in my configuration file:

```
app.use(multer({dest: './app/controller/store'}).single('photo'));
```

I would truly appreciate it if you steer me towards the right path, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

.single('parameter') means the input field's name is 'parameter'

In your case:

```
app.use(multer({dest: './app/controller/store'}).single('photo'));
```

You passed a 'photo' argument into single func.

Then your form should look like this, change it:

```
..
    ..
    <input type="file" name="photo">
    ..
..
```